# When using POST with Fetch API to send user input to php file / Session variable it returns undefined array key

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I'm trying to send user inputs with Fetch API to my php file using the POST method. I've tried this with XMLHttprequests and has no issue but now I want to start using Fetch API. When I use the GET method to send the variable to the $_SESSION array I have no problem and I can echo it out. When I use the POST method it would return always "Undefined array key" for the variables.

I'm new to this so any help is much appreciated.

**PHP**

```
<?php
// a sessions start
session_start();
// session variable
$number1 = $_POST['n1'];
$number2 = $_POST['n2'];

$_SESSION['numbers'] = $_POST;

echo $_SESSION['numbers']['n1'];
echo $_SESSION['numbers']['n2'];
?>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addNumbers);

function addNumbers(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById('one').value;
var input2 = document.getElementById('two').value;
    fetch('serv.php',{
        method:"POST",
        body:'n1='+input1+'&n2='+input2,
        header: {   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        
    }).then((response) => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
            output.innerHTML += data;
            
        })
}
```

I know that I should check if the Session variable is empty or isset but i removed it just for visibility purposes.

A print_r($_POST) output is :

```
Array ( )
```

A print_r($_SESSION) is :

```
Array ( [number2] => 
        [num1] => 
        [num2] => 
        [numbers] => Array ( ) 
)
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please show a `print_r($_POST);` and a `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: print_r($_POST) output is : Array ( ) 
print_r($_SESSION) is : Array ( [number2] => [num1] => [num2] => [numbers] => Array ( ) )

Comment: Typo: the property for telling `fetch` what headers to send is `headers` not `header`. (So you are failing to override `Content-Type: text/plain` so PHP isn't parsing the request body and populating `$_POST`).

Comment: Thanks @Quentin this solved my issue.

Comment: I would like to thank the original poster for their question as it actually solved a query I had - which was how to POST actual data that could be read in PHP like normally submitted form data. It was the content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded that did the trick for me :)